# Flexbox: Display columns horizontally?

Tags: css

All the code can be found in the JS fiddle below I thought it would be easier that way. I am trying to display the Flexbox items horizontally, so that the first 8 and 4 columns are beside each other.

I then want to add the 12 on a totally new line, underneath the 8 and 4 and not beside it, extending the pages length horiztonally and having that horrible scroll.

What have I tried?

```
.container {
    display: flex; /* or inline-flex */
}
```

So the above code just makes it all go side by side, no matter how many columns you do or if it exceeds 12, I want it to work pretty much exactly like bootstraps grid system if that makes sense.

https://jsfiddle.net/d35g2mra/1/

Answer (score 0):

Wrap **only** the wanted divs in `div` and `dispaly:flex` them (in the same way you can wrap the images section if you want to)

```css
body {
  background-color: whitesmoke;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
}

#nav {
  background-color: #333;
  color: #ffff;
  padding: 16px;
}

hr {
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.wrap{
  display:flex;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-GB">
  <div id="nav">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          lol
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container"><br><br><br>
    <div class="wrap">
     <div class="col-md-8">
        I need to put a pretty picture here.
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        I will place some sort of box here.
      </div>
    </div>
     
      <hr>
      <br>
      <div class="col-md-12">
        Trending Pages
        <div class="col-md-2"><img src="https://phpsocial.com/demo/thumb/a/112/112/1171031268_435428908_1738535611.png"></div>
        <div class="col-md-2"><img src="https://phpsocial.com/demo/thumb/a/112/112/1171031268_435428908_1738535611.png"></div>
        <div class="col-md-2"><img src="https://phpsocial.com/demo/thumb/a/112/112/1171031268_435428908_1738535611.png"></div>
        <div class="col-md-2"><img src="https://phpsocial.com/demo/thumb/a/112/112/1171031268_435428908_1738535611.png"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

```css
body {
  background-color: whitesmoke;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  overflow-x:hidden;
 
}

#nav {
  background-color: #333;
  color: #ffff;
  padding: 16px;
}
hr {
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en-GB">

  <head>
    <title>{{ config('website.name') }}</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flexboxgrid/6.3.1/flexboxgrid.css" type="text/css">
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="nav">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          lol
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8">
           <img src="https://phpsocial.com/demo/thumb/a/112/112/1171031268_435428908_1738535611.png">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
           I will place some sort of box here.
        </div>
      </div>
      <hr>
      <div class="container">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <span>Trending Pages</span>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-2">
          <img src="https://phpsocial.com/demo/thumb/a/112/112/1171031268_435428908_1738535611.png">
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-2"><img src="https://phpsocial.com/demo/thumb/a/112/112/1171031268_435428908_1738535611.png"></div>
          <div class="col-md-2"><img src="https://phpsocial.com/demo/thumb/a/112/112/1171031268_435428908_1738535611.png"></div>
          <div class="col-md-2">
          <img src="https://phpsocial.com/demo/thumb/a/112/112/1171031268_435428908_1738535611.png">
          </div>
         </div>
      </div>
      </div>
      
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```